# Different results between General Linear Models in SAS and R

Tags: r, sas, glm

I am trying to convert a SAS code, which computes least square means of a general linear model, to R. I have tried but do not get identical results. I have not done any Sas before, and only marginal familiar with R.

My SAS code is as follows:

```
proc glm data=data;
class x y; 
model w= z x v z*x z*v x*v z*x*v;
lsmeans x;
```

My corresponding R code is:

```
m1 <- lm(w ~ z + x + v + z*x + z*v + x*v + z*x*v, data = data) 
summary(m1)

lsm <- lsmeans(m1, ~x)
s <- summary(lsm)
class(s)
s[c("lsmean")]
```

The difference (SasLsMeans-RLsMeans) in result are between 0.03 and 0.09 eight x’s.

I have tried to do some comparison for ‘smaller’ formulas for the glm:

`SAS: z x, R: z+x` -> decmial difference on 7th decimal. (almost identical)

`SAS: z x v, R: z+x+v` -> Same difference for all x's: 0.064

`SAS: z x v z*x, R: z+x+v+z*x` - > Same difference for all x’s: 0.064

`SAS: z x v z*x z*v, R: z+x+v+z*x+z*v` - > Same difference for all x’s: 0.063

I am wondering if all these differences are due to decimal roundings? Or if it has anything do with the underlying models in SAS and R?

Comment: For questions on Stack Overflow you should include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used for testing.  Question about underlying models are probably a better fit for [stats.se].

Comment: SAS makes different assumptions. Try the sasLM package.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, I agree, but I think `lsmeans`/`emmeans` results should be the same?

Comment: (also, an additive model with all-numeric predictors should give the same results -- construction of model matrices should be the same in this case?)

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, I was not aware of that. I am not able to include the dataset, since it belongs to a third-party. I will remember to use Cross Validated the next time.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. I have tried the sasLM package, but I get the errorthat it cannot allocate vector of size XXX. The data set is quite large (>200.000 rows).

Comment: If the purpose is just to empirically establish whether SAS gives same or different results it would be sufficient to use a subset of your data. in SAS, sasLM and in what you originally tried.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks, I manage to get it to work by using the sasLM package and LSM function. Now I only get a small error on the third decimal, which I consider sufficient. Thank you!